# Check if a field group's subfields have values

Tags: 7, entities

Is it possible to check if a fieldset's subfields have values?
If none of the fieldset's fields have values it would return null.

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'group_name');
if ($field) {
   // At least 1 of it's sub-fields has a value!
}
else{
   // None of it's subfields have values!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try use the `field_group_field_group_is_empty()` function.

From the [field_group](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/field_group/tree/field_group.api.php?h=7.x-2.x&id=5d1ce8e2438674d4c127c1a164bfa8b5a91d8fa6#n288) module itself:

```
  // Example from field_group itself to unset empty elements.
  if ($display) {
    foreach (element_children($element) as $name) {
      if (in_array($name, $groups)) {
        if (field_group_field_group_is_empty($element[$name], $groups)) {
          unset($element[$name]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```